# How to conditionally disable a synchronized block in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

Can I do something like that:

```
synchronized(isSynchronized ? myLock : null) {

}
```

I want to disable/enable synchronization through a flag. Is it possible?

Comment: No, it isn't. Give us the bigger picture. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter passed into the `synchronized` block is not a statement but rather a object to synchronize upon (the mutex). To disable synchronization for whatever reason you should encase the statement in a if-condition as such:

```
if(condition){
    synchronized(myLock){
        // Critical segment
    }
}
```

note however, if the evaluation of `condition` can be dependent on several threads (i.e. multiple writes to a boolean from different threads) you may need to use an existing thread-safe mechanism like `AtomicBoolean` as such:

```
AtomicBoolean condition = ... // defined elsewhere

if(condition.get()){
    synchronized(myLock){
        // Critical segment
    }
}
```

if you need conditional synchronization upon a synchronized method, remove the synchronized keyword from the method declaration and move it into the body:

```
public synchronized void foo(){
    // Critical segment
}
```

to

```
public void foo(){
    if(condition){
        synchronized(this){
            // Critical segment
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lock (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) and lock it manually.

```
if (shouldSync) {
  lock.lock();
}
try {
  // do your stuff
} finally { 
  if (shouldSync) {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no such method as release on lock. Also what if in OP's stuff throws exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can't synchronize of null. So if you have another mutex, then definately you could do something like:

```
synchronized(isSynchronized ? myLock : myLock2) {
}
```

else you could check and enter the critical section like:

```
if (isSynchronized) {
    synchronized(myLock) {..}
}
```

Comment: Problem with this appraoch is that I have to make my synchronized block a method. Is that any escape from that?

Comment: So in that case you would need something like `if (isSynchronized) { mymethod(); }` And make sure your isSynchronized variable is volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use an `if` before hand. Also, make sure the variable `isSynchronized` is marked [`volatile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4).

```
if (isSynchronized) {
  synchronized(myLock) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

of course, that won't be synchronized when `isSynchronized` is false. And that doesn't sound like a great idea, if it's thread-safe it shouldn't be synchronized. If it isn't thread safe, it should be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for starters:

```
if (isSynchronized) {
    synchronized(lock) { return doStuff(...); }
} else {
    return doStuff(...);
}

private MyType doStuff(...) {
    ...
}
```